# Java - What does it mean by writing return ""; in a method?

Tags: java

I am a Java beginner. When reading a block of Java code, I came across a method which includes a if condition and `return "";`

Just wondering what does `return "";` means…

The example code is below:

```
public String parse(String d, String u) {

    if (d.isEmpty() || u.isEmpty()){
        return "";
    }
    ...
}
```

Could someone explain further to me please? Thank you

Comment: It's just an empty string.

Comment: What about it are you asking about? Do you know what `return` does? Do you know what `""` is?

Comment: An empty `String` is returned. That's because the programmer didn't want to return `null` or an uninitialized `String`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm just doing to break this down line by line for you.

```
public String parse(String d, String u)
```

This line declares a new method which:

- Is called parse
- Returns a string
- Takes two strings as inputs

If youre wondering specifically about the fact that the keyword `return` is used then [you can look at this answer I found from a quick google search.](https://www.quora.com/What-is-the-meaning-of-void-in-java)

```
if (d.isEmpty() || u.isEmpty())
```

This line checks if the input d is empty OR (expressed by '||') input u is empty. Essentially checking if either of the inputs are empty.

```
return "";
```

If the above if statement is met, `return"";` will be run. This means the method will return an empty String.

I can only guess what is at the end of the method you've posted but to help you further I've whipped up a quick example.

```
public String parse(String d, String u) {

       if (d.isEmpty() || u.isEmpty()){
            return "";
        } else {
            return "not empty"; 
        }
}

public static void main(String[] args)
{
    String d = "hi";
    String u = ""; //empty

    String result = parse(d, u);
    System.out.println(result);

    String d = "hi";
    String u = "bye"

    result = parse(d, u);
    System.out.println(result);
}
```

The output we get in the console is:

```
empty
not empty
```

Comment: Thank you! Realy makes sense

Comment: No problem, if there's anything else you need help with feel free to comment it, if you could click the little check mark net to this answer to let people know it's solved that'd be wonderful!

Answer (score 0):

This is probably a check before starting parsing those string, you dont want to parse empty strings cause it probably has to do with the parsing mechenism, so it start from checking validation of the arguments, and return empty `String` if it invalid

Comment: Thank you! this is really well explained!

Comment: @MengranLi dont forget to mark it as the correct answer if it does :)